# Aggregate documents in a tree like structure

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection filled with documents like the following:

```
{
  area: "Some area",
  group: "group name", // area includes different groups
  name: "name" // there are many names in each group
}
```

And for the front-end i need a tree-like structure:

```
{ _id: "area name",
  name: "same as _id",
  ap: {
    children: [
      { name: "group name, children: [ { name: "name from the doc" } ] }, 
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm interested in how hard is it do this with aggregation framework or is it possible to do so? Or better to compute this on client-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be possible to get the current aggregation framework to output a similar structure with a lot of effort (and a very lengthy pipeline), it wouldn't be simple or a good fit. The aggregation framework is designed to aggregate documents and produce summaries, groups, etc. While it can do projections of data, you'll find it to be cumbersome if you need more than a few fields in the results.

It is also worth looking at the limitations of the framework currently [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/). The result as of 2.4 cannot exceed 16MB total.

I'd recommend you build the structure on the client. It frees the database from doing busy work and distributes the effort to clients. If it's a large structure, you should consider caching the results anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to WiredPrairies accepted answer, if you need the size/boundaries of the tree map quickly, you can do so as shown below.

```
db.appconsumers.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$taxonomies"},
    {$project:
        {"tier1" : "$taxonomies.tier1",
        "tier2" : "$taxonomies.tier2",
        "tier3" : "$taxonomies.tier3",
        "tier4" : "$taxonomies.tier4",
        "tier5" : "$taxonomies.tier5"}},
    {$group:
        {_id: {"tier1":"$tier1", "tier2": "$tier2", "tier3":"$tier3", "tier4":"$tier4","tier5":"$tier5"}, count:{$sum: 1}}})
```

Output

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "tier1" : "Arts & Entertainment",
        "tier2" : "Movies",
        "tier3" : "Kill Bill"
    },
    "count" : 15
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "tier1" : "Arts & Entertainment",
        "tier2" : "Movies"
    },
    "count" : 20
}, 
{
    "_id" : {
        "tier1" : "Arts & Entertainment",
        "tier2" : "Movies",
        "tier3" : "Kill Bill",
        "tier4" : "Main characters",
        "tier5" : "Bill"
    },
    "count" : 5
}
```